# how to substract sql tables (but keep 'null' )

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

have a table where i run two commands with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DésignationBDC2) FROM pdc where BDC3 like '%01|06|02%'
SELECT DISTINCT(DésignationBDC2) FROM pdc where Id=60
```

then i get this:

```
DésignationBDC2
018 Rose
047 Noir
507 Poudre
545 Rouge
556 Navy
F72 Caramel
280 Saphir
```

and this

```
DésignationBDC2
047 Noir
545 Rouge
556 Navy
F72 Caramel
```

i'd like to substract these tables to get this:

```
DésignationBDC2
null
047 Noir
null
545 Rouge
556 Navy
F72 Caramel
null
```

how can i do ?
thanks

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`! Remove those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT DésignationBDC2 FROM ...` to make code clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using the left join

```
select 
    T2.* 
from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DesignationBDC2 FROM pdc where BDC3 like '%01|06|02%') AS T1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DesignationBDC2 FROM pdc where Id=60) AS T2 ON T1.DesignationBDC2 = T2.DesignationBDC2
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend aggregation:

```
select (case when id = 60 then null else DésignationBDC2 end)
from pdc
where DésignationBDC2 like '%01|06|02%'
group by DésignationBDC2;
```

Answer (score 0):

using the method you proposed, i tried to join those two tables like this:

```
select 
    T2.* 
from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DésignationBDC2 FROM pdc2 where BDC3 like '%01|06|02%') AS T1
    LEFT JOIN (select DésignationBDC2, COULEUR from pdc2 where Id=60) AS T2 ON T1.DésignationBDC2 = T2.DésignationBDC2
```

these tables are : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yCCo.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJA34.png)

however, i get this :[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFHF9.png)
and as you can see, the order of "DésignationBDC2" is lost from the first table.
How can i avoid this ?